# Schedule the same task for different time interval

Tags: java, scheduler, timer-jobs

Is it possible to schedule one task for different time intervals? Here is the fixed interval example:

```js
Timer gTimer = new Timer();
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

ScheduleClass scheduleClass = new ScheduleClass();
gTimer.schedule(scheduleClass, startDate.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 2); //interval is 2 minutes
```

This snippet of the scheduleClass has the run function and it is successful to run every 2 minutes. My question is: How can I set the interval to every 2, 5 and 7 minutes?

When I copy the scheduler three times it throws this error:

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled`

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Have a look at Quartz, it seems that it has more fine-grained scheduling options, like CRON expressions : https://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: You can use `gTimer.schedule(scheduleClass::run, startDate.getTime(), 1000 * 60 * 2);` syntax to clone the class every time you schedule it, so it never thinks that they are the same instance

Comment: `scheduleClass::run` allowed only at source level 1.8 or above, but the project is not allow to be updated.